# Problems with Pycharm & Google App Engine rendering requested post data

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm an application developing noob.  I'm using pycharm to code out of and I have it linked up with google app engine, so I can test my code with the convenient run & debug capabilities provided by JetBrains.  I've got a separate file in the same directory called validation.py containing the true valid_month, valid_day, valid_year functions.  The problem I've run into is this (I'm confused at this point).  This code, earlier was generating an html page with the form data displayed (I'm thinking this has something to do with my get(self) function being changed to write_form because it wasn't earlier), but even when the form data was displayed and I would enter the user-required information the page would just manipulate the data like "get" and put the data in the URL.  Now, with write_form I'm not even generating a page I just get errors.  Bear in mind, I'm doing this via the CS253 Udacity Web Development course, so my code is mimicking that of the class, with the exception that I'm using webapp and not webapp2.

**Here is the code**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from validation import valid_day, valid_month, valid_year

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
month_abbvs = dict((m[:3], m) for m in months)

def valid_month(user_month):
    return True

def valid_day(user_day):
    return True

def valid_year(user_year):
    return True


form ="""
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday?
    <br>
    <label>Month <input type="text" name="month" value="%(month)s"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Day <input type="text" name="day" value="%(day)s"></label>
    <br>
    <label>Year <input type="text" name="year" value="%(year)s"></label>
    <div style="color:red">%(error)s</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""



class OTWHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))


        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("Invalid entry")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("That is totally a valid day!")


def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', OTWHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)
```

**Here is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Madrigal\PycharmProjects\OTW\otw.py", line 42, in get
    self.write_form()
  File "C:\Users\Madrigal\PycharmProjects\OTW\otw.py", line 39, in write_form
    self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error})
KeyError: 'month'
```

Your responses are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with the dictionary you are passing into the `form` string. If you take a look at your `form`, you will see values that look like `%(month)s` - what this means is that the `form` is expecting an argument called `month` to be passed into it, and it is going to return the corresponding value. The problem now is that you are (I'm assuming) issuing a `GET` request to the page, and when that happens, the dictionary of values you pass to the `form` only has one value - `error`. Therefore when the `form` looks for `month`, it can't find anything and returns a KeyError.

One simple example that would get this working would be to do this:

```
def write_form(self, error=""):
    test_date = datetime.date(2012, 11, 26)
    my_values = {
        'month': test_date.month, 
        'day': test_date.day, 
        'year': test_date.year, 
        'error': error
        }
    self.response.out.write(form % my_values)
```

It would be better to make the date parameters a part of the function, but hopefully the concept makes sense - for every `%(something)`-formatted string in your `form`, you need to pass in a corresponding key/value argument so that it knows what to load.

Answer (score 1):

I've already changed this around, by the way.  Copied the code before I did this I guess.

```
def write_form(self, error="", month="", day="", year=""):
   self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error, "month": month, "day": day, "year": year} )
```